# flask Create social share components

Tags: python, flask, share

I'm looking create a 'share link' I found https://pypi.org/project/Flask-Share/0.1.0/ this link from google, it helped me a lot but I would like to remove some un-required links and add some new links like Whatsapp

```
from flask_share import Share
share = Share(app)

{{ share.create(title='Share with: ', content='WhatsApp') }}


{{ share.load() }}
{{ share.create(title='Share with: ') }}
```

TypeError: create() got an unexpected keyword argument 'content'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not how the `create` method is to be used, according to the [documentation](https://flask-share.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#api). To specify which apps are to be supplied, you must use the `sites` kwarg. For example, `sites="whatsapp"`.

Documentation Quote:

> sites – a string that consist of sites, separate by comma. supported site name: weibo, wechat, douban, facebook, twitter, google, linkedin, qq, qzone. for example: ‘weibo, wechat, qq’.

I don't know if WhatsApp is supported, but if it were your code would look like this:

```py
from flask_share import Share
share = Share(app)

{{ share.create(title='Share with: ', sites='whatsapp') }}


{{ share.load() }}
{{ share.create(title='Share with: ') }}
```

Answer (score 0):

**It doesn't look like this is possible.**

Take a look at `__init__.py` on the [Flask Share GitHub page](https://github.com/greyli/flask-share/blob/bba77015ad647d4fc57ebba9fa9f5ed6bec7ef70/flask_share/__init__.py).  See the following source code comments:

```
>:param sites: a string that consist of sites, separate by comma.
                  supported site name: weibo, wechat, douban, facebook, twitter,
                  google, linkedin, qq, qzone.
                  for example: `'weibo, wechat, qq'`.
```

As you can see, `whatsapp` does not appear at all within this list.  In addition, [a simple text search of the Flask Share source code](https://github.com/greyli/flask-share/search?q=whatsapp&unscoped_q=whatsapp) indicates that the phrase "whatsapp" does not appear at all within the code.  Finally, [the screenshots of the demo](https://flask-share.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) (as there is no actual, working demo online) indicate that whatsapp, also, is not supported.

**If you want to share with WhatsApp, you will need an application package that supports it!**

*Want a reliable project?*  I maintain a social share URL's project on GitHub, and we are maintaining links to WhatsApp.  Just download the code and run it!  Check us out! [GitHub: Social Share URLs](https://github.com/bradvin/social-share-urls).

[image: Social Share URLs]